# Set all categories in firebase & react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have two buttons that filter what category is displayed. The filtering is working fine and records are displayed correctly. Right now only one category is displayed at the begining. My question is how do I set category so it displays all records at the begining?
Here is my code:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState( "design");

  function useCourses() {
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      db.collection("projects")
        .where("category", "==", category)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          let data = [];
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push({
              ...doc.data(),
              id: doc.id,
            });
            return data;
          });

          setCourses(data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }, [category]);

    return courses;
  }

  const courses = useCourses();
```

and buttons:

```
        <button
          className="projects__controls__button"
          onClick={() => setCategory("web")}
          style={{ color: theme.color, borderColor: theme.color }}
        >
          Web
        </button>
        <button
          className="projects__controls__button"
          onClick={() => setCategory("design")}
          style={{ color: theme.color, borderColor: theme.color }}
        >
          Design
        </button>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: So you are trying to show all categories in the beginning, and you want to filter only when the user explicitly selects a category, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the initial value of `category` as null or an empty string.

Then in the subsequent code,

```
useEffect(() => {
      let collection = db.collection("projects");
      
      if (category) {
         collection = collection.where("category", "==", category);
      }
        
      collection.get()...
.
.
.
```